# Failing to update rails 5.1.2 to 5.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and I'm trying to updating rails in a project.

I changed `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'`

for `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'` in my Gemfile.

Execute `bundle update rails` and got

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activerecord":
   In Gemfile:
    administrate (~> 0.8.1) was resolved to 0.8.1, which depends on
       activerecord (>= 4.2, < 5.2)

     administrate (~> 0.8.1) was resolved to 0.8.1, which depends on
       kaminari (>= 1.0) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
         kaminari-activerecord (= 1.1.1) was resolved to 1.1.1, which depends on
           activerecord

     rails (~> 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
       activerecord (= 5.2.3)
```

I tried deleting the `Gemfile.lock` and executing `bundle install` and got:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers (~> 0.10.6) was resolved to 0.10.9, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6)

    administrate (~> 0.8.1) was resolved to 0.8.1, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.2, < 5.2)

    rails (~> 5.2.3) was resolved to 5.2.3, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.2.3)

    rspec-rails (~> 3.5) was resolved to 3.8.2, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 3.0)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "administrate":
   In Gemfile:
     administrate (~> 0.8.1)

     administrate-field-carrierwave (~> 0.2.0) was resolved to 0.2.0, which depends on
       administrate (< 1.0.0)

     administrate-field-ckeditor (~> 0.0.9) was resolved to 0.0.9, which depends on
       administrate (>= 0.3, < 1.0)
```

And no Gemfile.lock was created

Comment: try just `gem update` this will update all outdated gems.

Comment: but would this update everything in my Gemfile?

Comment: yes. It will update all gems. But if you know all gems that are causing this problem, you can update these gems before updating rails... but I think the easy way is to update everything

Answer (score 0):

Run `bundle update`

Then run `bundle install` which handles changes to the Gemfile and `bundle update` upgrades gems that are already managed by Bundler.